# jQuery Datatables change value of a column based on condition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I have Datatables which is working fine. However I want to tweak it a bit. As you can see I have this condition:

```
if ( data.status == 0 )
```

Which means that if the `status` is equal to zero I will make the text color red and green otherwise. However I also want to change the text of the `data.status` Coz it is `0` or `1`. How can I make the text appear `Pending` if zero and `Approved` if 1.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#LeaveList').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: 'leave-list',
             "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                if ( data.status == 0 ) {
                    $('td', row).eq(6).addClass('text-danger');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('td', row).eq(6).addClass('text-success');
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
                {data: 'employee_name', name: 'employee_name'},
                {data: 'employee_id', name: 'employee_id'},
                {data: 'from_date', name: 'from_date'},
                {data: 'to_date', name: 'to_date'},
                {data: 'leave_type', name: 'leave_type'},
               // {data: 'department', name: 'department'},
                {data: 'status', name: 'status'},
                {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
                {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: true, searchable: true}
            ]
        });

    }); 
    </script>
```

I want to this in this jquery part not in the query of data

Comment: The correct way to do this is by using the column `render` property.  There is a similar question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941916/render-jquery-datatable-boolean-column-with-check-and-x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23941916/render-jquery-datatable-boolean-column-with-check-and-x)

Answer (score 3):

Assume that your current code is working properly. Then you only need to modify the `createdRow` part like so:

```
...
createdRow: function ( row, data, index ) {
  if ( data.status == 0 ) {
    $('td', row).eq(6).addClass('text-danger').text('Pending');
  } else {
    $('td', row).eq(6).addClass('text-success').text('Approved');
  }
},
...
```

However, as pointed out by markpsmith, the cleaner way is to use the `render` options. You may read about the [`columns.render` here](http://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render).

Answer (score 2):

You can use fnCreateCell to modify your data.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#LeaveList').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: 'leave-list',
        columns: [
            {data: 'id', name: 'id'},
            {data: 'employee_name', name: 'employee_name'},
            {data: 'employee_id', name: 'employee_id'},
            {data: 'from_date', name: 'from_date'},
            {data: 'to_date', name: 'to_date'},
            {data: 'leave_type', name: 'leave_type'},
           // {data: 'department', name: 'department'},
            {data: 'status', name: 'status',
            "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {

                   if (sData) {
                         $(nTd).addClass('text-success');
                   }else{
                         $(nTd).addClass('text-danger'); 
                   }
                }               
            },
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: true, searchable: true}
        ]
    });

});
```